# Difference of &.class vs & .class

Tags: css, sass

&.class vs & .class: Is placing a space in between make a difference?

In my sass file I have this code:

```css
.parentClass {
  &.childClass {}
}
```

They want me to put a space in between the childClass and '&' symbol:

```css
.parentClass {
  & .childClass {}
}
```

Does that make any difference?

Comment: Check this out https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is this:

```
.parentClass {
  &.childClass {}
}
```

will actually generate the selector `.parentClass.childClass`, meaning that you are selecting for an element that has **both** classes, e.g. `<div class="parentClass childClass">`. This is likely *not* the case you want. Meanwhile, this:

```
.parentClass {
  & .childClass {}
}
```

will compile to:

```
.parentClass .childClass {}
```

...which will select an element with the class `childClass` that is a child of an element with the class `parentClass`, e.g.:

```
<div class="parentClass">
    <div class="childClass"></div>
</div>
```

---

As @deceze has pointed out, in your simplified example the `&` is not necessary, if all you want is to imply a hierarchical relationship, because it is syntactically identical to:

```
.parentClass {
  .childClass {}
}
```

...which also gives you `.parentClass .childClass {}`.

Comment: …which makes the `&` in `& .childClass` redundant really.

Comment: @deceze In OP's simplified example, definitely :) however, if OP wants to filter the selector based on any other additional condition on the parent class, then the `&` will be necessary, e.g. `&[title="foo"] .childClass` ;)

Comment: Sure, only in the `&<space>...` case is it redundant.

Comment: *that is a child of an element* No. It will select an element that is a **descendant**, it doesn't have to be a child (which would require the `>` child selector). Otherwise, good answer.

Answer (score 2):

For the second case, there is no significance of putting "&" symbol because

```
.parentClass {
  & .childClass {}
}
```

and

```
.parentClass {
  .childClass {}
}
```

will result in same compiled CSS as:

```
.parentClass .childClass {
}
```